# Cannot find symbols/variables for Pack class, solution?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, shuffle

This is probably something incredably simple it will annoy me completely, but admitidly I'm stuck.

I am close to finishing an assignment, but I am hitting a dead end due to the system not being able to find any symbols in this class, refered to as the Pack class. I do have a seperate class called the PlayingCard class which is pretty much complete, but I now need this class with a seperate tester to complete the assignment.

Here's the code, and then I will explain what I want to do with it.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack 
{
PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52];

public Pack()
{
    // Setting up array
    String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
    String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

    // Intialising array
    Pack()   // Error 1
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.length(); i++)  // Error 2
        {
            PlayingCard[i] = i;  // Error 3
        }
    }
}

public void shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
        PlayingCard[i] = rand;   // Error 3
    }
}

@Override
public String toString()
{

}
}
```

This is very much like a card game class. I have a method called Pack, in which I need to construct a Pack of 52 cards sorted by different suits and ranks. The shuffle class is obvious, it needs to be able to shuffle a constructed deck. I have resorted to making a set of arrays for the playing cards. Though `PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52]` was specifically inserted into a template for the assignment.

Now, the problem is that the NetBeans system is unable to find the symbols for Pack, PlayingCard and length() even though PlayingCard is part of a seperate class in the same package, and Pack is already a part of the class.

So, what am I getting wrong here?

EDIT:
The errors I get are like this:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method Pack()
location: class Pack

; expected
```

---

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method length()
location: class PlayingCard()
```

---

```
cannot find symbol
location: variable PlayingCard
location: class Pack
```

These will be represented as 1, 2, 3 on the code above in order.

EDIT 2:
The PlayingCard at the top of the code may be a constructor (I'm using a template given for the assignment to set up the code), see new link.

```
public class Pack 
{
PlayingCard[] cards;

public Pack()
{
    this.cards = new PlayingCard[52];
    // Setting up array
    String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
    String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", 
        "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

    // Intialising array
    Pack()
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.length(); i++)
        {
            PlayingCard[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still getting the error's shown in the first block of code.

Comment: If PlayingCard is a type name, you can't use indexing on it: `PlayingCard[i]`.

Comment: Shuffling an array `PlayingCards[] cards`, i.e., a deck of cards, isn't  done by assigning random integers to playing cards, which isn't permitted anyway since PlayingCards are PlayingCards and integers are integers.

Comment: When you ask about a compilation error, ALWAYS post the exact and complete error message, and tell which line of code it refers to.

Comment: @laune I am probably looking like an idiot but I don't think I follow, are you saying I can't actualy use `PlayingCard[] cards` and need to set up a different array or not at all? Besides, PlayingCard is actually the name of a class in the same package.

Comment: I will find the error messages hang on.

Comment: Where is PlayingCard defined? Is it a class? I think it should be cards[i] instead of PlayingCard[i] in the code!

Comment: Added the errors. As for PlayingCard. Elsewhere in the package it is a class. Do you need me to add everything I have done to get a clearer picture?

Comment: If it is something ridiculously obvious, someone point out?

Comment: I have added an altered Pack Method, if I am looking at the template correctly the PlayingCard at the top may be a constructor, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these are the errors:

Error3: PlayingCard is class not an array. cards is the array, change

```
/*change this PlayingCard[i] = i */  
/*to*/ cards[i] = i;
```

Error2: length is not a function but a variable.

```
/*change this PlayingCard.length(); */  
    /*to*/ cards.length;
```

Again get length from cards (Your array is called cards, not PlayingCard)

Error1: Why do you have a function inside a function? What do you want to do here?

Try this code:-

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack 
{
PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52];

public Pack()
{
    // Setting up array
    String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
    String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};

    // Intialising array

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) 
        {
            cards[i] = i;
        }   
}

public void shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
        cards[i] = rand;   // Error 3
    }
}

@Override
public String toString()
{

}
}
```

PS: There are several issues in your code. I would recommend you to follow some tutorials here - http://codingbat.com/ to understand the language basics well.

Comment: I have done the changes, but now I am running into a problem with cards being unable to convert int to PlayingCard. It could be a problem relating to the PlayingCard class if you want me to add it or if there is something in the Pack Class I am missing?

Comment: @SIHB007 See my 2nd comment after your Q. You try to put an int(eger) value on `cards[i]`, i.e., a `PlayingCard`. These types are incompatible, hence the error (If you do this in real life, it's called "marking cards", and something will happen to you - it depends on the company in which you are playing. ;-) )

Comment: @laune I can understand that, but it's not exactly explaining on how I can fix the problem. I have changed PlayingCard to int so cards will work, but PlayingCard was specifically stated in a template. Is there anyway to use PlayingCard and int? Like some kind of backdoor?